The request failed to reach my Django view
This is a web Django project, In my navbar I have a drop down that contains buttons to exploring products depending on their category, here is the code of the drop down list snippet in the main template:
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Product Categories
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <button data-category = "cloths" class="product-category dropdown-item btn btn-light">Cloths</button>
            <button data-category = "sport" class="product-category dropdown-item btn btn-light">Sport</button>
            <button data-category = "household items" class="product-category dropdown-item btn btn-light">Household items</button>
          </div>
        </li>

and I used csrf token for post requests, and here is the javascript snippet:
var productCategories = document.getElementsByClassName("product-category")
for ( i = 0 ; i < productCategories.length ; i ++ )
{
    productCategories[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        var category = this.dataset.category
        console.log(category)
        exploringCategory(category)
    })
}
function exploringCategory(category)
{
    var url = 'category_exploring/'
    fetch(url,{
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({'category' : category})
    })
}

and here is the view:
def category_exploring(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    category = data['category']
    print('*')
    print(category)
    user = request.user
    products = Product.objects.filter(category=category)
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer = user, complete = False)
    cartItems = order.get_total_order_cnt
    context = {'products' : products, 'cartItems': cartItems}
    return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)

the problem is nothing is happening when I click the buttons, what should I do?

What does the console of the Django server shows, and the network console in the browser?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

how are you obtaining that csrftoken value?

You don't seem to be doing anything after making the request (Ideally you should do something with the response)? Are you really sure you want to call that URL via AJAX rather than using a form?

I see you are trying to render a template in the category_exploring() function so why not just create an a tag that points to that url. this way no js and no post requests are necessary...
<a href="{% url 'category_exploring' 'cloths' %}" data-category = "cloths" class="product-category dropdown-item btn btn-light">Cloths</a>
<a href="{% url 'category_exploring' 'sport' %}" data-category = "sport" class="product-category dropdown-item btn btn-light">Sport</a>
<a href="{% url 'category_exploring' 'household-items' %}" data-category = "household items" class="product-category dropdown-item btn btn-light">Household items</a>

just update the category_exploring() function to accept the category_slug and do all the filtering with this variable...
def category_exploring(request, category_slug):
    pass

and the url
path("category_exploring/<category_slug>/list", category_exploring, name='category_exploring')


I did't know about this way for passing info directly with the URL, thanks, it worked!
